# Edit Table data with Spring-Boot & Thymeleaf

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, thymeleaf

I am still learning Thymeleaf, Bootstrap, and JQuery so please pardon my ignorance.  I have a spring-boot app with Thymeleaf and Bootstrap as the UI.   I have a list of Users that I display in a table and would like to edit them.  My current thinking is that the user could select the icon on the row and that record is populated into a modal dialog form, where it could be updated with a call.  Not sure if that is best or not, but it's where I am right now.

Here is my html:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="well well-lg">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h5>CNET OFAC Users</h5>

                <div th:if="${userList != null and not #lists.isEmpty(userList)}">
                    Found <span th:text="${#lists.size(userList)}"></span> Users
                </div>
                <div th:if="${userList == null or #lists.isEmpty(userList)}">
                    <div>"No Users were found"</div>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>UserName</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                        <th>Active</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="user : ${userList}">
                        <td th:text="${user.username}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${user.companyName}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${user.roles[0].authorities}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${user.enabled}"></td>
                        <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>

                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button data-target="#loginModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-default">Add User</button>

                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

which includes the update form:

    
        
            
                ×
                Edit User

```
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal bv-form" action="addUser" th:action="@{/addUser}" th:object="${user}" method="put" id="loginForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Username</label>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <input type="password" name="cpassword" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Company</label>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <input type="text" name="companyName" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Status</label>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <select class="form-control" name="enabled" th:field="*{enabled}">
                            <option value="true">Active</option>
                            <option value="false">Inactive</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-5 control-label">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Update</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

Where I am stuck is how to populate this modal with the record on the row where the edit button was clicked.   What is the best way to populate the modal with that record value so I can then submit it to my spring-mvc controller for updating?

Answer (score 0):

Is this for an Admin interface?  Sounds like it as that would be a place where you would be seeing a list of users and editing them.

An easier way to accomplish this would be to take them to an edit user page instead of doing it in a modal.  Everything would be straight forward HTML/CSS in this case and you can use Spring/Hibernate validation to validate the form.

Comment: Yes, this is an admin page.  I have a list of users and I thought about inline editing, but didn't know how to do that either - which is how I ended up with the modal.  Can I make the rows in the table editable and then have it save (PUT)?

Comment: You can do it inline for sure.  I just thought you were making it tougher on yourself (more work).  Specifically I'm thinking how you will handle the error conditions.  You might end up having to write some custom stuff.  Because 1) you will doing the PUT via ajax and you need to render the errors correctly for the appropriate fields or 2) You will do a browser post, in which case if there is an error you will need to redraw the page in it's edit state with errors.  If you get to define the requirements for this page, it should take less time to just take them to another page to do the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very much clear with your code. I assume you tried to open a modal for you each data set in the table. If I am right then there is a thing you need to notice first. When you are populating modal for you each row of a table that is generated dynamically, you cant simply add modal with a single ID. you need to generate modal ID for each of your table rows. Hence why don't you change your code like this-

```html
    <td>

    <a data-toggle="modal" th:href="'#'+${user.id}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
         
    <div class="modal fade" id="view-news" 
th:id="${news.id}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
      
      <!-- Every other codes for you modal -->
      
      
    </div>

    </td>
```

what I did here basically creating modal dynamically for each row and assigning them a id what will then used to find that.